# mysql-connector won't import into script in pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I have successfully installed mysql-connector using pip.

```
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector
Running setup.py install for mysql-connector ... done
Successfully installed mysql-connector-2.1.6
```

However, in PyCharm when I have a script that uses the line:

```
import mysql-connector
```

PyCharm gives me an error saying there isn't a package called **"mysql"** installed. Is there some sort of syntax that should be used to indicate that the entire package name contains the "-" and is not just "mysql"?

When I run my script in IDLE, mysql.connector imports just fine. (I changed it to mysql-connector after seeing the "-" in the name of the package and having trouble in PyCharm.)

EDIT: per @FlyingTeller's suggestions, in the terminal, "where python" returns C:...Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe. "where pip" returns ...Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe. The interpreter in PyCharm for this project is this same filepath & exe as "where python" in the terminal.

Per @Tushar's comment, this program isn't using a virtual environment and the mysql-connector library is already present in the Preferences->Project->Python Interpreter.

Thanks for the feedback and any additional guidance you may be able to provide.

Comment: If you have a comment to an answer, then pls don't add it to your question, because the author of the answer will not be notified in any way. I just stumpled on this by pure chance. Always comment on the respective post if you want to adress the author of it. Adding additional info to your question to indicate what you have tried so far is of course good and needed, but you should also comment on an answer to notify the author that he/she should take another look

Comment: besides from that, have you also changed your import to `import mysql.connector`?

Comment: I am kinda new to these forums. A sincere thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because you are using a virtual environment inside pyCharm, while you might have installed the library using system's default pip.

Check `Preferences->Project->Python Interpreter` inside Pycharm, and see if your library is listed there. If not, install it using **`+`** icon. Normally, if you use pyCharm's inbuilt terminal, it is already using the same virtual env as your project. So using pip there may help.

Usage syntax is as below:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
         user='root',
         password='#####',
         host='127.0.0.1',
         database='some_db')

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to import the connector as

```
import mysql.connector
```

Check the examples in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) for this

If that doesn't work, then there might be an inconsistency between the interpreter that pycharm uses and the one you installed the package for. In pycharm, go to

```
File->Settings->Project Interpreter
```

In the terminal, enter

```
where python #Windows
which python #Linux
```

and also

```
where/which pip
```

make sure that the interpreter configured in pycharm is the same that appears when typing `which/where python` in the command line/shell. Also make sure that `pip` also points to the same python distribution.

Comment: in the terminal, "where python" returns C:...Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe. "where pip" returns ...Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe. The interpreter in PyCharm for this project is this same filepath & exe as "where python" in the terminal.  <br/> I did change the import in my mail script file to mysql.connector, and ignored the error that PyCharm was giving me "Package requirement 'mysql' is not satisfied". And everything ran properly. So perhaps this is an instance where I should "Ignore requirement" in PyCharm?

Answer (score 3):

Go to project interpreter and download mysql-connector.You need to install it also in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact issue as well, after a while i solved it by **simply changing the name of my script in PyCharm**, turns out i had named my script mysql.py (because it was my first time attempting to connect it to python) and it was critically interfering with the import.

TLDR: **Change the name file if it's asssigned as mysql.py**, as it takes priority over the mysql-connector and prevents it from being imported, even if installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

People have commented with reasonable responses (and I'm sure OP is good on this by now) but they weren't super clear to me...

Don't use "pip3 install" in terminal in your pycharm project.  In fact, uninstall any mysql connectors you have already using this method.

So now that you have verified there are no other mysql connector packages...  Add the package "mysql-connector-python" using the Python Interpreter only (in preferences) in your pycharm project.  Now the package should work!