# Trying to insert data into mysql database but i am getting the error as module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connector'

Tags: python, mysql

I have imported the connector as well using both the

```
import mysql.connector (or) `import mysql.connector as mysql`

con = mysql.connector(host="localhost", user="root", password="root", database="pythontkinter")
   cursor = con.cursor()
   cursor.execute("insert into student values('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+phone+"')")
   cursor.execute("commit")
MessageBox.showInfo("Insert Status","Inserted Successfully")
   con.close()
```

To be noted i am processing this in windows os system...And my file name is Python-tkinter.

Comment: Only the second import version should have produced that error. What error did using `import mysql.connector` create?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql-connector won't import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52308452/7414759)

Comment: I am getting the same error for both the syntax's for the import part.